# Specifically when is InvalidOperationException thrown during serialization/deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I keep some object data in an xml file for persistence. When my program runs, it first reads the xml file and loads its data into memory. During various times throughout the program's runtime it saves the data to the same xml file by overwriting the whole file with the new data in memory.

The save and load operations are very similar and look like this:

```
public void SaveProfiles()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(profilesDir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(profilesDir);
        }
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Profile>));
            StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(profilesDir + profilesSaveFile);
            serializer.Serialize(streamwriter, profileList);
        }

        //streamwriter and other exceptions removed here for brevity

        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //handle error
        }
        finally
        {
            //do some stuff
        }  
    }
```

I've come to realize that should `InvalidOperationException` be thrown during

```
serializer.Serialize(streamwriter, profileList);
```

I would lose data because the file would already be overwritten by

```
StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(profilesDir + profilesSaveFile);
```

on the previous line.

So I would like to know `exactly under what circumstances is InvalidOperationException thrown during serialization and deserialization?`

I haven't been able to find much on this, but from my own trial and error I know that it is thrown when the `typeof` for the `XMLSerializer` differs from the type in the xml.

Are there any other?

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx): `InvalidOperationException: An error occurred during serialization. The original exception is available using the InnerException property.`

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "not much". What errors CAN occur during serialization?

Comment: According to another [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx): `In most cases, Serialize, Deserialize and even the XmlSerializer constructor throw a rather generic System.InvalidOperationException when an error occurs. This exception type can occur in many places in the .NET Framework; it is not specific to the XmlSerializer at all.` I don't think it's very easy to figure out when exactly the error might occur.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking :)